# How to find words that follow a specific order

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I am trying to write a script(script1.sh) that finds every possible word when given a jumble of letters.

- The words must start with the first letter of the jumble and end with
  the last letter.
- The letters of the word need to follow the order of the letters in the jumble.
- Each letter in the jumble can be used more than once.

So this

```
./script1.sh "qwertyuytresdftyuiokn"
```

should output `queen` and `question` but not "quieten" because "e" comes before "u" and "i" in the jumble.

I tried assigning the first, last and the remaining letters to variables, then using egrep to find the words but I couldn't find a way to use the order of letters. So this one gives me invalid words as well.

```
#!/bin/bash

first_letter=$(echo $@ | cut -c1)
last_letter=$(echo $@ |rev| cut -c1)
remaining_letters=$(echo $@ | cut -c2- | rev | cut -c2-)

grep -E "^$first_letter[$remaining_letters]*$last_letter$" /usr/share/dict/words
```

Then I tried turning the jumble into an array but then again I couldn't find a way find words that obey the order in the jumble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
pttrn="^$(printf '%s' "$1" | sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1*/g' -e 's/\*/\\+/' -e 's/\*$/\\+/')"'$'
grep "$pttrn" /usr/share/dict/words
```

A pattern is obtained from the first argument by injecting `*` after each character. Then the first `*` is changed to `\+`; so is the last `*`. Additionally `^` and `$` are added. Your example input generates the following pattern:

```
^q\+w*e*r*t*y*u*y*t*r*e*s*d*f*t*y*u*i*o*k*n\+$
```

This pattern is the right pattern for `grep`. `q` must appear at least one time at the beginning, `n` must appear at least one time at the end. Each letter in the middle may appear zero or more times, the order is maintained.

Note the script is dumb. If you provide input with `.`, `[`, `]` or so then you will get a regular expression beyond the specification. Provide sane input or expand the script to validate it.

---

Examples:

```
$ ./script1.sh qwertyuytresdftyuiokn
queen
question
$ ./script1.sh te
tee
$ ./script1.sh superuser
seer
serer
spur
super
supper
surer
$
```

Comment: The "dumbness" of the code could be remedied by putting each character into their own `[X]` pattern, or escaping it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to approach it

First, filter the wordlist down to just those words that start and end with the same letters as the jumble. For example, if the jumble is passed as positional parameter `$1` (and assuming a recent `bash` shell)

```
grep -x "${1:0:1}.*${1:(-1):1}" /usr/share/dict/words
```

Then take each of these words and blow it apart into a regex - I can't think of a "nice" way to do that, but with GNU sed you could do for example

```
$ sed -E 's/(.)\1*/+.*\1/2g' <<< "queen"
q+.*u+.*e+.*n
```

Now test the jumble against each generated pattern.

Putting it all together:

```
$ cat script1 
#!/bin/bash

wordlist=/usr/share/dict/words

while IFS= read -r word; do 
  grep -qEx "$(sed -E 's/(.)\1*/+.*\1/2g' <<< "$word")" <<< "$1" && printf '%s\n' "$word"
done < <(grep -x "${1:0:1}.*${1:(-1):1}" "$wordlist")
```

then

```
$ ./script1 qwertyuytresdftyuiokn
queen
question
```

Comment: You may _possibly_ want to additionally escape each character in the input string, or put them into square brackets, maybe.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another (run in `bash`)
The `python` code generates the regular expression and feeds it to `grep`. `grep` then works on output from the venerable `look` utility, which performs a binary search to pull back all the `/usr/share/dict/words` words that start with `q` in the example. `grep` thus has a greatly reduced set of words to search through

```
python3 -c 'import sys
arr = list(sys.argv[1])
print(*arr, sep="*")
' $1 | grep -x -f - <(look ${1:0:1})
```

Alternately, a `look` + `python3` solution that avoids regular expressions

```
look q | ./finder.py "qwertyuytresdftyuiokn"
```

where `finder.py` is as follows:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from itertools import groupby

seek_word = sys.argv[1]
for word in sys.stdin:
    orig_word = word.strip()
    word = ''.join(k for k, g in groupby(orig_word)) 
    s_w = iter(seek_word)
    i_word = iter(word)
    if all(c in s_w for c in i_word) and not next(s_w, None):
        print(orig_word)
```